# What´s the best protocol for connecting a java spring based backend with an java-based frontend (tapestry or someting else)?

Tags: rest, soap, protocol-buffers

i´m about to do a project, where a Sring based backend should connect with a frontend which is java based too (tapestry or sometging - i don´t really know at this moment).

So, im currently thinkning about which is the best protocol for the data exchange between these to systems?

currently these are my points
- http(soap)
- http(rest)
- http(google protocol buffers)

I would be very pleased if you have any suggestions or anyone can help me pushing into the right way for this decision :)

Best regards from Hamburg

Answer (score 0):

RMI is worth considering. It can be troublesome to get traffic through firewalls, but it does make transferring almost any Java object across the wire very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using JSON over HTTP; can be very high performance (see [this benchmark](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/)), readable, has good support for libraries. Many developers have misconception that JSON is mostly for AJAX; but JSON actually works pretty nicely as a service-to-service format too (and for storage on document databases too).
Oh and Spring (version 3.0) has rather good support for JSON as well.